# How do I find the most similar phrase in "Extending Multi-Sense Word Embedding to Phrases and Sentences for Unsupervised Semantic Applications"?

Tags: information-retrieval

This question is about de paper [Extending Multi-Sense Word Embedding to Phrases and Sentences for Unsupervised Semantic Applications](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.15330.pdf), depicted in the following picture:

[image]

I am interested in more information about the problem of given a new phrase, find the most similar phrase among **billions** of phrases.

Is it possible to formulate the above problem as a nearest neighbor in euclidean space or a dot product? What is the complexity (time and space) of the algorithm for the embedding a new phrase and for "querying" a new similar phrase? (please also add the time here in seconds because I am interested in the behaviour of the algorithm for very large applications...)

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is simply to find the most similar phrases, you do not need to use the methods in this paper. As the unsupervised phrase experiments show in this paper, multiple embeddings do not improve the similarity measurement.

There are many techniques you can use to find the nearest neighbors efficiently if you represent each phrase as a single embedding. One of the popular libraries is faiss (https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss). faiss can handle both l2 distance or dot product. You can check their documentation or paper to know how efficient those methods could be.

Comment: You have written "multiple embeddings do not improve the similarity measurement" in accordance with what is written in your abstract "multifacet embeddings provide an interpretable semantic representation but do not outperform the single-facet baseline". Nonetheless, your algorithm significantly outperforms BERT for phrase similarity in terms of AUC/F1/Accuracy (look table 4 of your algorithm). So, why is your algorithm much better than BERT? Is the addition of co-occuring words responsible for such high performance?

Comment: I am very interested in the fragment of co-occuring words. I am a very active user of Google, which  has many times retrieved good answers for my verbose queries I asked in my life. I believe the good retrieval performance was due to a good data structure for term proximity not existing in other search engines... This is why I am so interested in you work. I couldn't find any attempt to add co-occuring words to BERT for similar tasks like phrase similarity or question answer.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and thoroughly explain the mechanism of finding an answer using nearest neighbor under euclidean metric in the presence of multiple embeddings for a phrase?

Comment: The main reason that our method could significantly outperform BERT is that BERT is trained on sentences rather than phrases. I know a recent work that improves the phrase embedding from BERT: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2109.06304.pdf . That might be more like what you want. I do not know whether there exists a method that can efficiently retrieve the nearest neighbors if the phrases are represented by multiple embeddings.

Comment: As for me your article is very interesting and I want to write a new article based on your paper, so please edit your answer explaining the mechanism of your algorithm for searching for a new similar sentence given other sentences. Please publish your code on github asap @Haw-Shiuan Chang. thanks

Comment: In the paper, we do not claim that we have an efficient way to do the nearest neighbor search when using the multiple embedding representation. All the experiments are done by pairwise comparison. You can see my code here https://github.com/iesl/NSD_for_sentence_embedding.git. I haven't had time to organize it or write a readme. Please send emails to me if you have questions about the code.